# Existence of basis $B$ such that $[T]_B=\cdots$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a vector space with dimension $n$ and let $T: V\rightarrow V$ satisfy $T^2=0$.
>
> (a) Prove Im$ T \subseteq$  Ker $T$ and $\dim($Ker$(T))\geq \frac{n}{2}$ (SOLVED BY ME)
>
> (b) Assume $n=3, T\neq 0$ Prove there exists a basis $B$ of $V$ such that $[T]_B=\begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
>  0&0  & 0\\ 
> 0 &0 & 0
> \end{bmatrix}$

My attempt at (b):

By (a) we know $\dim(\ker T)\geq \frac{3}{2}$, hence it's either 2 or 3. Assuming it's 3 we get $V=\ker T$ which contradicts $T\neq 0$. So $\dim(\ker T)=2$

Basically we can take a basis of $\ker T$, $(v_1,v_2)$. And we need to show there exists $v_3\in V$ such that $T(v_3)=v_1$ and $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is a basic of $V$ (ahm show theyr'e linearly independent). this is have I'm having trouble with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $v_3\notin \text{Ker }T$ and note that $v_1:=T(v_3)\in \text{Ker }T\setminus\{0\}$ since $T(v_3)\neq 0$ but $T^2(v_3)=0$. Now, complete $(v_1)$ to obtain a basis $(v_1,v_2)$ of $\text{Ker}\,T$.

**Edit:** Why is $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ a basis of $V$? Since $\dim V=3$, it suffices to prove that $v_3$ is independent from $(v_1,v_2)$. But, if it were false, then $v_3$ would belong to $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle =\text{Ker}\,T$, which is not the case. Hence, $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is linearly independent and is a basis of $V$.

Comment: How do you know that $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is a basis of $V$?

Comment: See my edit above.